# How is the Gas Price field in Metamask populated?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, metamask, javascript, evm

I have an evm compatible blockchain with a price limit set to 10000.

However when I go to submit a transaction to a validator, Metamask populates the gas price at 0:
[image]

How can I ensure transactions are submitted with a minimum gas price?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by updating the `price-limit` CLI param on validator startup and updating the gasPrice param in `hardhat.config.js`

1. Stop validators
   pidof polygon-edge
   sudo kill -9 process_id_1 process_id_2 process_id_3
2. Restart validtors with `--price-limit 1`
3. Edit gasPrice in hardhat.config.js in your smart contracts folder
   [image]
4. Redeploy contracts and Metamask should populate properly